# How can I parse the following JSON structure in Go

Tags: json, parsing, go

In Go, how can I parse the following JSON?
I know to use `struct` to parse, but the keys are different for each entry, also they are not fixed, they can be more or less.

```
{
  "consul": [],
  "docker": [],
  "etcd": ["etcd"],
  "kubernetes": ["secure"],
  "mantl-api": [],
  "marathon": ["marathon"],
  "mesos": ["agent", "follower", "leader", "master"],
  "mesos-consul": [],
  "zookeeper": ["mantl"]
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: what's inside consul, docker and maltl-api?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If json values are always an `[]string` you can convert it with

```
json.Unmarshal(value, &map[string][]string)
```

But if not, best way to do this is Unmarshal JSON in a map[string]interface{} and check each field type you want to.

Comment: Is there no way Consul provide any inernal parser to  parse data if in the form .HCL or .YAML?

Answer (score 2):

Unmarshal the JSON to a map type: `map[string][]string`

```
var m map[string][]string
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/bR_igb55tQ)

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide Go' structure for more fluent unmarshaling...

```
type Rec struct {
    Consul      []string // `json:"consul"`
    Docker      []string // `json:"docker"`
    Etcd        []string // `json:"etcd"`
    Kubernetes  []string // `json:"kubernetes"`
    MantlApi    []string // `json:"mantl-api"`
    Marathon    []string // `json:"marathon"`
    Mesos       []string // `json:"mesos"`
    MesosConsul []string // `json:"mesos-consul"`
    Zookeeper   []string // `json:"zookeeper"`
}
```

[Working example on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rtNW8aqkvK)